# Pass parameter from batch file to sqlite script

Tags: csv, batch-file, sqlite

I want to batch import multiple *.CSV files to a SQLite3 database using a batch command line.

I have a batch file(loader.bat) which calls loader.sql to import the csv file into test.db (using sqlite3.exe).

```
sqlite3.exe test.db ".read loader.sql"
```

loader.sql is a sqlite script that imports data.csv into a table (tb_data)

```
.import data.csv tb_data
```

This works for importing a single file (data.csv). I want to import all the *.csv files (eg data123.csv, data456.csv, data789.csv) in a folder into the same table(tb_data).

I am thinking of using a for loop in the batch script to iterate through the files.

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
    echo %%a
    sqlite3.exe test.db ".read loader.sql"
)
```

How do I pass the parameters from the batch script to the sqlite script(loader.sql)?

Answer (score 0):

Just combine all your `csv` files into one first and use your original command to load that:

```
copy *.csv combined.cv
```